# Recyclerview wrap_content with HasFixedSize within a NestedScrollview does not show items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

as the title . I am using Recyclerview to display my items. but I need more view above the Recyclerview(with wrap_content height) so I decided to use NestedScroll view. But the broblem is that when I set Recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true), the items dont show up . and when I set Recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(false). they show up. how can I set Recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true) and the items still showing up ?

this is the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/appbar_layout"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <include layout="@layout/searchbar_layout"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

this is the item row XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"


            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/row_main_infor_text_size"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/lightgrey_radius_20_bg"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:textAllCaps="true"

            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the JAVA code :

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager_VERTICAL = new LinearLayoutManager(ForwardMessage.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        rv_all_friends = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_all_friends);
        rv_all_friends.setLayoutManager(layoutManager_VERTICAL);
        rv_all_friends.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ((SimpleItemAnimator) rv_all_friends.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        rv_all_friends.setAdapter(mAllFriends_Adapter);
```

Comment: don't use the `RecylcerView` with `NestedScrollView` find another solution

Comment: First change height of `LinearLayout` from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`. Also remove `android:weightSum="1"` from list row item. Also set `rv_all_friends .setNestedScrolling(false)`

Comment: @StavroXhardha why ? Because I want other views scroll with recyclerview. any solution for my case

Comment: @Piyush let me try